# Testing a TCP/IP connection locally

Tags: java, tcp

Currently I have an application that connects to a Terminal Server over TCP/IP using an IP address and a port. Is it possible for me to create a mock TCP/IP connection locally on my laptop so I can make the application to connect to a specific IP and port on my laptop?

I am a noob at networking, so please execuse if the question isn't clear.

The reason I am trying to do this is, the application is listening to a specific port on a TCP/IP connection on the terminal server and I remotely send some data using VB macros to the same port. I would like to test the same locally in absence of a terminal server (just using my laptop) but when I run the application it can only connect using a TCP/IP connection.

The application is written in Java and can be run locally by providing an IP address and port to connect to, so I would like to see if I can make the application connect to my laptop as a TCP/IP connection.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Just run the mock on your local computer and on the client side use special `127.0.0.1` IP address or `localhost` name. On every computer it means *the same machine*. This is so-called loopback interface.

Comment: and can I connect to any open port available?

Comment: @Rishi: If you open any port on your laptop you can connect to that port using `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks I did use netstat -ano option to see the open ports and got connected.